# Masked textbox mask causes data type mismatch

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access-2010

I have a masked textbox with a mask for zip codes(00000-9999) and an access database field with long type.  When I enter a zipcode like 27101 the entry is added(though in access it is -27101), but it works.  If I add a full zip like 27101-1111, I get a data type mismatch error.  I tried removing the mask and entering 271012222 and it is added to the database.  ??

```
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Zip", mskZipCode.Text);
```

Comment: just a tought but if this has the potential to be a large application than only your contry the varchar option seem better to me. For example zip code from canada are j0j 0j0 (letter, number, letter, number, letter, number)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a type mismatch not because of the fact that you are masking but because you are entering invalid characters for a long type.

> I add a full zip like 27101-1111, I get a data type mismatch error. I tried removing the mask and entering 271012222 and it is added to the database. ??

This is your problem. Your type in Access is long but you are entering a non numeric character '-'. The reason that you are able to enter 271012222 is because you avoided entering the '-'. If this is going to be a zip code field and you want the full zip code, I suggest changing the type of the field in Access to be varchar(10) (or the Access equivalent).